# Rails asset pipeline flattens directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-sync

I've been using [`asset_sync`](https://github.com/AssetSync/asset_sync), to move our static assets to Amazon S3, and I've noticed that when I precompile my assets (using `foreman run rake assets:precompile`), the base directories get flattened. They go from:

```
/app
  /assets/
    /images
      image.png
      image2.png
      /subdir
        image3.png
    /javascripts
      script.js
    /stylesheets
      style.css
```

To:

```
/public
  /assets/
    image.png
    image2.png
    /subdir
      image3.png
    script.js
    style.css
```

It keeps any subdirectories, but the base directories get removed for some reason.

Is it possible to disable this? I'd like to keep my S3 assets organized into directories. I could probably resolve this by adding additional directories so that the structure is the following.

```
/app
  /assets/
    /images
      /images
        image.png
        image2.png
        /subdir
          image3.png
    /javascripts
      /javascripts
        script.js
    /stylesheets
      /stylesheets
        style.css
```

But that just seems like a dirty solution.

I'm configuring my assets for precompiling with:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = []
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['application.js']
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += Loader.js_files
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['*.css', '*.png', '*.svg', '*.jpg']
```

My environment has the following variables":

```
ASSET_SYNC_GZIP_COMPRESSION=true
ASSET_SYNC_MANIFEST=true
ASSET_SYNC_EXISTING_REMOTE_FILES=keep
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxx
FOG_DIRECTORY=aws-example
FOG_PREFIX=/assets/
FOG_PROVIDER=AWS
FOG_REGION=us-west-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured asset_sync correctly for the application you are creating?

```
AssetSync.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'AWS'
  config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']
  config.aws_access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  config.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  config.prefix = 'assets'
  config.public_path = Pathname('./public')
end
```

Depending on the type of application you need to configure the prefix and the public_path. Check out the Sinatra/Rack support section https://github.com/AssetSync/asset_sync for more information. Hope puts you on the right path.